# Install Segoe UI Symbol with Inno Setup on Windows 7

Tags: windows, fonts, installation, inno-setup

I am using Windows 8 on my development machine and I am installing a program on a tablet computer that runs Windows 7.

I need to install a newer version of Segoe UI Symbol on the tablet during installation. I am using Inno Setup and the following line compiles just fine:

```
Source: "C:\PathHere\seguisym.ttf"; DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "Segoe UI Symbol"; Flags: ignoreversion uninsneveruninstall
```

I can install other fonts just fine but no Segoe UI Symbol.

Are there known problems with trying to install Segoe UI Symbol version 5.9 on Windows 7?

(If I manually install the font, it installs no problems at all.)

Comment: I assume you've completed the appropriate licensing steps with Microsoft to distribute this font?

Comment: @Deanna I had not even considered licensing the font. The font is simply a new version (5.9) of the Segoe UI Symbol font that already came with Windows 7. The new font file was gained from my Windows 8 development computer in the Fonts dir. Do I need to license a font for this scenario based on your experience and could this be the reason my installation has failed?

Comment: I doubt that's the reason it's failing but the font is owned by Microsoft for their use and nothing says you're free to redistribute it, regardless of version number.

Comment: @Deanna I was unaware of any such restrictions on fonts so I thank-you for pointing this out to me.